# slidify - How to create slide layouts

Tags: html, css, r, slidify

I'm working on a customized slidify presentation for a conference I have to do in a few weeks in a university (PhD level). I would like to create DRY layouts in `assets/layouts` directory to simplify slide design and keep things DRY : title-only, plan, sub-title-only, title-and-body, sub-title-and-two-cols, title, sub-title-and-body, caption, blank.

I visited the [ramnathv github repository](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify) and [specific slidify Website page to customize layouts](http://ramnathv.github.io/slidify/customize.html).

I have also checked the [several questions asked on slidify specific subject](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slidify/hot).

I have successfully create a `slide.css`file in `assets/css`, and add an logo in `assets/img`to customize the aspect and the css attributes for my presentation (customizing the `tilte-slide` & `slide`).

I would like to create an `html`file in `assets/layouts`for each of my presentation slide type : `title-only.html`, `plan.html`, `sub-title.htmll`, `title-and-body.html`, `sub-title-and-two-cols.html`, `title.html`, `sub-title-and-body.html`, `caption.html`, `blank.html`.

I have found a useful question answered by ramnathv [here](http://ramnathv.github.io/slidify/customize.html) to create my `sub-title-and-two-cols.html` file in the `Layouts with Parameters`part.

I need now to transfer my css attributes created in my 'slide.css`file in the`assets/css` directory.

For example, I would like to create a `plan.html` file. Here is the code I would like to compute from the `slide.css`file  for the `plan.html` file :

- Modify the font:

  ```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT');
  ```
- Modify the title slide attributes:

  ```
  /* slide h2 css modification = for page title left - blue */
  slide:not(.segue) h2{
  font-family:'Old Standard TT', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: normal;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #0000ff;
  }
  ```
- modify the text content attributes:

  ```
   /* slide article & section css modification = normal lighter darkgrey */
   article p, article li, article li.build, section p, section li{
   font-family: 'Old Standard TT', sans-serif;
   font-size:22px;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: lighter;
   text-transform: normal;
   text-align: left ;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   color: #4c4c4c;
   }
  ```

I would like to know how can I transfer this css attributes in my `plan.html` file:

```
    ---
    layout: slide
    ---
    {{{ content }}}  
    ...
    ...
```

And then, for the 'plan' slide, I will mark them like this:

```
    --- &plan

    ### a header

    some text
```

Which should get the css attributes specified just before.